# How to create fixed height 1st column layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, height, fixed

How to create fixed height 1st column layout?
I saw a kevinrose.com blog and i liked it, simple and clean layout, i wanted to use that layout so i was trying to create it but i stuck with this fixed height, i can easily set fixed bar like header, but column, i dont know how to do it
example:

```
#sidebar
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
#article
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;            
}
#like
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;   

    z-index:-5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position:fixed on the sidebar, and offset the rest using a margin

```
#sidebar
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
}
#article
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed is how you achieve that. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/wpHMA/

```
.wrap {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
 position:relative;
}
.sidebar {
 background:#333;
 color:#fff;
 width:25%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.content {
 width:75%;
 float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your given example "kevinrose.com" left panel is fixed position structure.
You can use following css/html code structure

Css

```
.leftPan{
    width:27%;
    background-color:#CCC;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    min-height:100%;
}
.rightPan{
    margin-left:27%;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#999;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="leftPan">
Left Panel
</div>
<div class="rightPan">
Right Panel
</div>
```

here is [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/nvr39/1/)